# react JS i18n using in functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have lots of functions like this:

```
export function dialogContent() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;

    switch (this.state.dialogHandlerVariable) {
        //Delete changeLog
        case 0:
            return (<div> {t("dialog.dashboard.changelog.deleteChangelog.body")}</div>);
    }
}
```

but here I got an error. -> t is not a function ..

because this is missing:

```
export default compose(
    translate('translations'),
    connect()
)(LanguageChooser);
```

how can I add the translate('translations') part to a function?

thanks

Comment: If you are using `dialogContent` as a component it is **stateless**. So no `state`, `this`, etc.

Comment: Problem is that I need this part `translate('translations'),` in my function

Comment: Then just add it :) . How do you use `dialogContent`?

Comment: but where and how? 

dialogContent is an exported function, I bind it in the constructor of a component

Comment: Plz add the part where you use the function otherwise the question is not clear and not useful for future readers. You need to use `translate` HOC on the component where you are using `dialogContent`

Comment: that was the hint thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The translate hoc is only needed for components -> it asserts components get rerendered on translation change or if set so the component waits for translation files to be loaded before initial render.

To use i18next inside a function, just:

```
import i18n from '../i18n'; // assuming you got an i18n instance configured and exported like in the samples - else just import i18n from 'i18next';

export function dialogContent() {
    const t = i18n.t;

    switch (this.state.dialogHandlerVariable) {
        //Delete changeLog
        case 0:
            return (<div> {t("dialog.dashboard.changelog.deleteChangelog.body")}</div>);
    }
}
```

Just make sure you loaded the translations before calling your functions.

Comment: cont { t } = i18n;